# Looking for alternative to dynamically creating Kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a service that fetches a snapshot of some information about entities in our system and holds on to that for later processing. Currently in the later processing stages we fetch the information using http.

I want to use Kafka to store this information by dynamically creating topics so that the snapshots aren't mixed up with each other. When the service fetches the entities it creates a unique topic and then each entity we fetch gets pushed to that topic. The later processing stages would be passed the topic as a parameter and can then read all the info at their own leisure.

The benefits of this would be:

1. Restarting the later stages processing can be made to just restart at the offset it has processed so far.
2. No need to worry about batching of requests (or stream processing the incoming http response) for the entities if there is a lot of them since we simply read one at a time.
3. Multiple consumer groups can easily be added later for other processing purposes.

However, Kafka/Zookeeper has some limits on the total number of topics/partitions it can support. As such I would need to delete them either after the processing is done or based on some arbitrary time passing. In addition since (some) of the processors would have to know when all the information has been read I would need to include some sort of "End of Stream" message on the topic.

Two general questions:

- Is it bad to dynamically create and delete Kafka topics like this?
- Is it bad to include an "End of Stream" type of message?

Main question:

- Is there an alternative to the above approach using static topics/partitions that doesn't entail having to hold onto the entities in memory until the processing should occur?

Comment: What about a distributed KV store?  ex: HBase or Cassandra

Comment: Kafka's main purpose is as a message bus in a pub / sub model.  It doesn't sound like you are really using it for that purpose here which makes me think it's not quite the right tool for this use case

Comment: @pwilmot I guess you might be right. It doesn't seem to fit nicely with what I want to do. A KV store might be a better alternative, esp. if it supports reading the results of a query as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one “compacted” topic can be an alternative